# Sit in vs. on a team?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know you would typically say: ‘he sits on the investment committee’ but if you are not high up in the hierarchy, can you nevertheless use the phrase ‘I sit on a team’? Or would ‘I sit in a team’ be more appropriate?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use *sit* at all with *team*. Far more natural and common is *I **am on** a team* or *I **belong to** a team.* The only reason *sit* is used in conjunction with *committee* is because it's a figurative analogy to committee members seated around a table. (Particular types of teams might also sit around tables, but that's not the common sense of the word.)

Comment: That does make sense, thank you!